# gnuplot conditional plotting with string fields

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot my data columns  "y":"x" only for "name" == "Q4".
Here is a data sample:

| name | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q4 | 1 | 3 |
| Q1 | 2 | 4 |

I tried with this:

```
plot "data.log" u ("name"=="Q4"?"y":NaN):("name"=="Q4"?"x":NaN))
```

And I have the following error: **Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected** 
Any guess how to do that with string in condition? Thanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been close. If you want to compare a string value of a column you have to use `strcol()` (check `help strcol`) and the string comparison `eq` (check `help operators binary`).

By the way, it is sufficient to set only one value (either x or y to `NaN`) to avoid plotting that datapoint.
Note, in the example below x and y are swapped compared to your example.

**Script:**

```
### filtering of strings with named columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
name   x   y
Q4     1   2
Q2     3   4
Q3     5   6
Q4     7   8
Q1     8  10
Q4    11  12
Q3    13  14
Q4    15  16
EOD

set datafile missing NaN

plot $Data u (strcol("name") eq "Q4" ? column("x") : NaN):"y" w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]